# ZXingBarcodeImageView rendering aspect ration on iOS virtual device

Tags: xamarin.forms, zxing.net

I am trying to generate and display barcode in Xamarin forms using following code.

```cs
barcode = new ZXingBarcodeImageView
{
    HeightRequest = 400,
    WidthRequest = 400
};
barcode.BarcodeFormat = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
barcode.BarcodeOptions.Width = 400;
barcode.BarcodeOptions.Height = 400;
barcode.BarcodeOptions.Margin = 10;
barcode.BarcodeValue = "ZXing.Net.Mobile";

Content = barcode;
```

The QR code is rendered fine in Android virtual device. On the other hand, in iOS device, a distorted QR code is rendered. The aspect ration of QR code rendered on iOS virtual device is not square as it supposed to be.

The QR code rendered on Android virtual device is verified using a mobile phone.

**Edit:**
Tried the following code as suggested by @wilson

```
        try
        {
            barcode = new ZXingBarcodeImageView
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            };
            barcode.BarcodeFormat = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
            barcode.BarcodeOptions.Width = 500;
            barcode.BarcodeOptions.Height = 500;
            barcode.BarcodeOptions.Margin = 10;
            barcode.BarcodeValue = "ZXing.Net.Mobile";

            Content = barcode;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Still, I see the same problem. When I tried the example code of @wilson and it works fine on iPhone simulator. Probably I should use content view as suggested.

**Edit 2**
I tried the stack layout as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AZCommute"
             x:Class="AZCommute.MainPage">
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label Text="QR Code Generator" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        <local:QRResult x:Name="qrResult"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

But, it was of no help. Nothing rendered on iOS. I tried by adding `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` while initializing the `ZXingBarcodeImageView` as shown below.

```
HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
WidthRequest = 410,
HeightRequest = 410,
```

Now, `ZXingBarcodeImageView` renders in iPhone simulator. But, the aspect ratio is lost (height > width ).
**Note:** I am using the `ContentView` with `StackLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the HorizontalOptions property like this:

```cs
barcode = new ZXingBarcodeImageView
{
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
};
barcode.BarcodeFormat = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
barcode.BarcodeOptions.Width = 500;
barcode.BarcodeOptions.Height = 500;
barcode.BarcodeValue = contentEntry.Text.Trim();
Content = barcode;
```

Or try creating a `ContentView` to show QRCode.

For more information see my [example](https://github.com/wilsonvargas/QRManager).

Comment: I did try the above code. Still same problem. Thank you very your example. It worked fine. I will refactor my code to `ContentView` and try again.

Comment: I refactored the code to use `ContentView`. I have tested the code across Android, Windows(UWP) and iOS. It works fine on Android and UWP. But, nothing is rendered on iOS simulator.

Comment: I am initializing ZXing forms using `ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put inside a StackLayout :)

```
        barcode = new ZXingBarcodeImageView
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        };

        barcode.BarcodeFormat = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
        barcode.BarcodeOptions.Width = 500;
        barcode.BarcodeOptions.Height = 500;
        barcode.BarcodeOptions.Margin = 10;
        barcode.BarcodeValue = "ZXing.Net.Mobile";

        Content = new StackLayout{
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,

            Children = {
            barcode
            }
        };
```

Comment: I did try `StackLayout` earlier. Still, the aspect ratio is lost. I have updated my question.